# How to calculate all possible combinations for a specific range of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math, combinatorics

I am very new to combinatorics. So that is why I am trying to figure out a way to generate all possible combinations for a specific range of numbers. The problem is that I really do not know how it works. I am trying to understand the logic for 2 days now. Every combination should have three numbers, stored in an extra array, for example: `[7,4,8]`. The user should be able to choose a range of numbers. I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me.

I was trying to use several for loops to get certain combinations. But that technique seems to be very very complicated and very very unclean. I am struggling with figuring out which possible combination types there can be. I want to write a function that looks like that:

```
function generateCombinations(min, max) {
   // LOGIC


   return combinations;
}

generateCombinations(0, 10);

// Example OUTPUT
/*

[
 [0,5,10],
 [10,10,10],
 [7,4,1],
. . .
]
*/
```

Hopefully you can help me.
Thank you

Comment: There are (max - min)! possible combinations. That could get out of hand very quickly.

Comment: @SimonGoater No, there are max!/((max-min)!) nr of possible combinations (permutations) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n

Comment: I think you need to better explain what your are trying to do. I thought you wanted the permutations of numbers between min and max but you are wanting something else.

Comment: Basically I want to write a function in which the user can enter a min parameter and a max parameter. Now the function should start generating all possible combinations for those numbers. Every combination should contain three numbers. So basically every number in the combination is only allowed to sit between the min and max. Here is a quick example: min=0; max=10. Now the function should generate all possible combinations with three numbers which sit in between the range from min to max. EXAMPLE OUTPUT  [0,0,0] [7,8,9] [10,10,10] [2,2,5] [1,1,9]. I hope that helps. Feel free to hit me up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very straightforward. Just use 3 nested loops(since your combination is of size 3) that iterate from min to max, keep collecting the combinations in an array and you are done.

```js
function generateCombinations(min, max){
let result = [];
 for(let i = min; i <= max; ++i){
   for(let j = min; j <= max; ++j){
      for(let k = min; k <= max; ++k){
        result.push([i, j, k]);
      }
    }
 }
 
 return result;
}

console.log(generateCombinations(0, 10));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally understood the logic behind that. Thank you for your time.